# UIView full screen

Tags: ios

I am creating a UIview using the following code:

```
UIview* baseView = [[UIview alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
//self.view = baseView;
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
baseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
baseView.alpha = 0.7;
```

The only problem is that even if I am using the mainScreen option to set it full screen, it appears full screen except for a 5cm line at the top of the UIWindow. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: self.view is the current view from interface builder

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, so the reason why this happens is because `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]` will return the frame of the window minus the size of the status bar if it is visible.

To fix it a simple way would be:

```
 UIView* baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                             0,
                                                             [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                                                             [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];
//self.view = baseView;
[self.view addSubview:baseView];
[baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
baseView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
baseView.alpha = 0.7;
```

Comment: wow great answer, I hadn't even thought about that. Yes the gap is the size of the status bar :)

Comment: I think you want [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds not [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame

Comment: it's working but it's shown under the tab bar and navigation bar.

Comment: this answer is valid for iOS v < 7.0

Comment: `applicationFrame` was deprecated in iOS 9.0